# Difference between app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) and app.use(express.static('public'));

Tags: express, dirname, route-parameters

I wonder if the following two are the same.

```js
(1) app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
(2) app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Because I think as long as `(2)` exists in the express server, the browser can serve up the `public` folder which is located in the root path and `__dirname` isn't required.

However, sometimes `(2)` doesn't work while `(1)` works such as if I render a ejs file in the dynamic route based on [Route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters).

What exactly is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

first of all __dirname have 3 usage, you can check [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-how-to-use__dirname):

**Making New Directories**

> To create a new directory in your index.js file, insert __dirname as the first argument to path.join() and the name of the new directory as the second

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '/pictures');

fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
```

**Pointing to Directories**

> Another unique feature is its ability to point to directories. In your index.js file, declare a variable and pass in the value of __dirname as the first argument in path.join(), and your directory containing static files as the second

```
express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'));
```

**Adding Files to a Directory**

> You may also add files to an existing directory. In your index.js
> file, declare a variable and include __dirname as the first argument
> and the file you want to add as the second If you run the express app
> from another directory(not root), it’s safer to use the absolute path
> of the directory that you want to serve, use `__dirname`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/pictures');

fs.openSync(filePath, 'hello.jpeg');
```

based on your example we can don't use __dirname but if you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve like this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```